# VS Code Jupyter py 3.11.5 output no truncating but scrolling

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, output, jupyter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NBfV.png)

Dataframe temp has 157 columns.
I want to see their types, but output gets truncated.

How to see this output with scrollable output or open in text editor view?

print() or display() did not work, and pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None) or pd.set_option('display.max_info_columns', None) also not working.

Additionally, my setting is below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOPot.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your output has 157 lines, and you have set the maximum number of lines to 100.

You can search for **Text Line Limit** in setiings then change the value to 200.

[image]

This is the same as adding `"notebook.output.textLineLimit": 1000,` to your `settings.json`.